# How to edit administrators group privileges in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

What I want to achieve is creating a group similar to Administrators and then edit privileges as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have domain controler, it's simple. Start Active directory, create new Security group and set Members, Members of and Security to reflect privileges you want to allow new group:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733146%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

More about AD Security groups:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579255%28v=ws.11%29.aspx